# Is it possible for the NServiceBus XmlSerializer to work with abstract types?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

We are using NSB4 with the built-in XML serializer. For some time now we have been sending a message of the following type

```
public interface IReply
{
    List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

Recently we had the need to work with different types of quotes, all of which inherit an abstract type, QuoteBase, so the reply now looks like this

```
public interface IReply
{
    List<QuoteBase> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

at runtime the quotes in the List are CarQuote or VanQuote. However we're finding that XML serializer won't work with Lists of abstract types. We get an exception of type MemberAccessException with a message of "Cannot create an abstract class". Does anyone know of any way around this?

Comment: What error message are you getting, and is it on the sending/publishing or receiving side?  Also, does the receiver of the message have knowledge of the derived types that are being put into the list?

Comment: @Phil have amended the question with some detail about the error. The receiver does have knowledge of the derived types.

Comment: See my comment to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689768/is-it-possible-to-get-at-the-current-incoming-nservicebus-message)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to make this work with an abstract class, but it does work with with an interface (e.g. IQuote).

Comment: Yes it does work with an interface although it only serializes the properties defined on that interface, which is a problem in our particular scenario, because the car- and van-specific properties will be omitted.

Comment: It's an answer.  "Is there a way around this?" "Yes, use an interface instead of an abstract class."  It may or may not be a correct answer, but it's an answer.