# Is it possible to get at the current incoming NServiceBus message?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

Using NServiceBus 4 it is possible to get at the message being handled by the current thread? IBus offers a CurrentMessageContext, but not the current message itself.

We would like to access the current message from our Ninject bindings so that we can control what types to inject into our message handlers.

Comment: I think more background is needed to understand your question.  You should not be changing your DI registrations at runtime (only at system startup).

Comment: The handler in question depends on IQuoteMapper, for which we have implementations named VanQuoteMapper and CarQuoteMapper. What we would like to do is check a property on the current message which tells us which type of vehicle we are working with, so we know which concrete mapper to inject in to the handler.

Comment: I would recommend injecting an abstract factory for this, although this is more of a DI concern than an NSB concern.  http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/

Comment: Phil's answer is correct, however, if you can create a separate message per quote (and a separate handler) then you will be going down a cleaner path, as this will leverage the event sourcing bit of messaging, and you should be able to apply different business rules easily and transparently, allowing for better maintainability, easier to change, and not be bound to the generic quote handler's behaviour. Dose this makes sense?

Comment: @Phil thanks, we have used something similar elsewhere in our app and may well switch to this technique

Comment: @Sean yes it does thanks. We will consider this option too along  with Phil's suggestion. Looks like the answer to my original question is "No" though :)

Comment: Well, the answer is: "No, there is nothing that works out of the box, IIRC, but you can easily achieve that using a IMutateOutgoingMessages or IMutateIncomingMessages mutator taht gives you the message before it is dispatched to the handlers, once you have the message you can build your own concept of message session handling and register it in the container with a scope per message call (or per thread in the end, unless you are running in asp.net)", but from a design POV Phil's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: @MauroServienti I'm not sure those interfaces provide access to the actual message, although I know you can work with the headers. I agree that Phil's suggestion is probably best.

Comment: @gilles27 yes, take a look here: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/nservicebus-message-mutators-sample